# Pass a variable from a function to another in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, function

I'm a newbie in Javascript world, and I searched a lot for a similar question but never worked for me.

So I'm working with a Bootstrap modal, I have 3 buttons with different names that opens a modal window. 
When I close the modal window I want an alert that show me the name of the button I've clicked.

For example, if I click on the button "Email Ted", when I close the modal the alert will say "You haven't sended the message to Ted".

I get the names from the attribute *data-name=""* in every button.

I also tried to insert the first function in a global variable, but didn't worked; so the code below is an idea to what I want to do.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      $("#exampleModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
        var recipient = button.data('name');
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
        return String(recipient);
      });


      $('#exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(recipient) {
        alert('The message will not be sended to ' + recipient);
      });

    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you have runnable code you can show it using the 
[Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)
in the editor below or in jsfiddle, codepen etc. 
You can include html and jquery.
This will speed up the debugging process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a working demo out of what I understand of your question.

Please have a look and ask for what you need to be explained.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  
  $("#open").on("click",function(){
    $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
  });
  
  var recipient="";
  
  $("#exampleModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    recipient = $("#open").data('name');
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
    return String(recipient);
  });


  $('#exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    alert('The message will not be sended to ' + recipient);
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="exampleModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" data-name="TEST Name">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="open" data-name="John Doh">Open modal</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code is working! I only added a button variable to catch the button target to show the correct name

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is important to mention that your snippet is not just general JavaScript, but the way Twitter Bootstrap works. There are no native shown and hidden events.
So you have custom events here. [Btw. referring to the bootstrap reference, it should be `shown.bs.modal` (recognize the missing 'n' in your code)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#how-it-works) or maybe I am wrong and they made some changes.

You could safe the button name in a variable like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      var recipient = null;

      $("#exampleModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
        var modal = $(this);
        recipient = button.data('name');
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
      });


      $('#exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(recipient) {
        if (recipient) {
            alert('The message will not be sended to ' + recipient);
            recipient = null; // important to reset this var for a second trigger
        }
      });

  });
```